Voltage offset from op-amp inverting amplifier
I'm trying to scale a digital I/O output from 0-3.3V to -1to-2V. I've decided to use an opamp inverter configuration so that 3.3V maps to -2V and 0V maps to -1V.
This would give:
Vout = -0.303 * Vin - 1
So I've designed the following schematic with a gain of 0.3:

The input at R1 is connected to either 3.3V or GND for now.
The problem is, when I input 3.3V, I get an output of almost -2.3V instead of -2.0V
and
when I input 0V, I get an output of around -1.3V instead of -1.0V.
So there's an offset of around 300mV coming in from somewhere that I don't understand. Could anyone help to explain what's going on please? I've also tried using the LTSPICE ideal 'opamp' model. Thanks

Your circuit behaves exactly like you would expect it to. If you derive an expression for the output voltage you would obtain
$$V_o = -\frac{R_2}{R_1}V_\text{in} - \left(1+\frac{R_2}{R_1}\right) \tag1$$
With component values it becomes
$$V_o = -0.3V_\text{in} - 1.3 \: \text{V} $$
Input voltage of 3.3 V gives: \$V_o = -0.3 \cdot 3.3 \: \text{V} - 1.3 \: \text{V}= -2.29 \: \text{V} \$
Input voltage of 0 V gives: \$V_o = -0.3 \cdot 0 \: \text{V} - 1.3 \: \text{V}= -1.3 \: \text{V} \$
Your mistake seems to be that you think the offset voltage is -1 V, but this is not the case with the given resistor values.

To add to @Carl's answer (+1), if you wanted to subtract 1V you could use this configuration:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
